# How to send JSON object along with file as multipart/form-data from Postman?

Tags: api, postman, multipartform-data, multipart

I am trying to make a post request to an api which uploads file to cloud native application. API takes 2 form parameters, one being the file itself and other being the JSON object which contains ID of the parent folder.

I've tried sending the raw JSON object itself, but its throwing 400 Bad request.[image]